# ¿Como puedo ordenar mejor mi codigo al filtrar productos por precio?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventos

Tengo una componente de mi proyecto, el cual en una pagina me muestra todos los productos y al costado me muestra botones para filtrar por distintos rangos de precio. El codigo del html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="list-group">
            <button class="list-group-item" (click)="allPrices()">Mostrar todos los productos</button>
            <ul>Precios
               <li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price1()">Menor a $300</button></li>
               <li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price2()">$300-$400</button></li>
               <li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price3()">$400 - $500</button></li>
               <li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price4()">$500 - $600</button></li>
               <li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price5()">Mayor a 600$</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Y el component.ts respectivo para ese codigo es el siguiente (en donde con ProductService llamo a mi servicio para traer primero todos mis productos y luego filtrarlos segun el precio que corresponda en cada funcion):

```
products: undefined | Product[];

  constructor(private product: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((data)=> {
        this.products=data;
      });
  }

  price1 () {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((products)=> {
        this.products = products.filter( product => {
          return product.price < 300 
        })
      });
  }

  price2 () {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((products)=> {
        this.products = products.filter( product => {
          return product.price > 300  && product.price < 400
        })
      });
  }

  price3 () {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((products)=> {
        this.products = products.filter( product => {
          return product.price > 400  && product.price < 500
        })
      });
  }

  price4 () {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((products)=> {
        this.products = products.filter( product => {
          return product.price > 500  && product.price < 600
        })
      });
  }

  price5 () {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((products)=> {
        this.products = products.filter( product => {
          return product.price > 500 
        })
      });
  }

  allPrices() {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((data)=> {
        this.products=data;
      });
  }
```

Como pueden ver, utilizo mucho codigo repetido. ¿Cual seria una buena forma de reutilizar codigo en este caso? Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas una función que resiva como argumento 2 valores:

- RangoInferior
- RangoSuperior

```
price (RangoInferior:Number, RangoSuperior:Number) {
    this.product.productList()
      .subscribe((products)=> {
        this.products = products.filter( product => {
          return (RangoInferior ? product.price>RangoInferior : true ) && (RangoSuperior? product.price<=RangoSuperior: true )
        })
      });
  }
```

Y luego en el HTML

```
<li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price(null,300)">Menor a $300</button></li>
<li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price(300,400)">$300-$400</button></li>
<li><button class="list-group-item" (click)="price(400,500)">$400 - $500</button></li>
<!-- ETC --!>
```

Comment: Excelente, acabo de aplicar lo que sugeris y se entiende perfecto la logica que aplicas. El unico problema es que en el component.ts me muestra "Parameter 'RangoInferior' implicitly has an 'any' type, igual que con RangoSuperior.

Comment: Problema solucionado. Al ser TS me falto colocar el tipo de dato que es RangoInferior y RangoSuperior. Lo solucione al colocar: price (RangoInferior: number, RangoSuperior: number). Muchas gracias @Yussef

Comment: @JoniArriazu Si! me faltaron los Number! Qué bueno te haya sido de utilidad. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos!